# @hotmail.com or @live.com?

Tags: outlook.com, office-365

is there any difference between email accounts created with either domain?advantages disadvantages?. There must be a reason for Microsoft creating the @live.com domain.

Comment: Regarding the answers below, suppose someone has a @hotmail account (or @live account). Does this mean that they can sign into @live as well with their current info, no extra steps taken, as a @live account, and vice versa? If so, is the mail 'shared' somehow between both accounts?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.  Just use the one that you prefer, if the address you want is still available.

Hotmail has 364 million users.  They started adding more domains so that more people could get the email address they wanted.  My mother managed to find her name available on `@hotmail.co.uk`, while she has to have a large number as a suffix on `@hotmail.com`.

If you have your own domain, [you can use it on Hotmail](https://domains.live.com/), while still being able to use the domain for websites.

Answer (score 2):

`@hotmail.com` is from before Microsoft began transitioning to their Windows Live products. `@live.com` is simply the new addresses they are handing out, though the old `@hotmail.com` addresses still work so that older users are not disrupted.

As far as a reason to get one or the other, I believe it's simply up to personal preference. Last I checked, all of the `@hotmail.com` addresses had been transitioned over to the new Windows Live email package, and provide the same features.

Comment: It's cause Hotmail was bought by Microsoft, hence the name

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft purchased the Live.com domain from Live networks. I think it was supposed to be a part of their movement towards a 'Live' interface with prettier interfaces and tools.

Whether they are different I do not know, as I stay well away from both.